# Multithreaded Windows Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

Is there any possibility for implementing multithreading in windows service?

I have to create a windows service that listens to a  message queue. When it receives a message , do some operaton in the background.

Comment: What "message queue" are you talking about? Services do not receive the window messages that windows running on the desktop do.

Comment: Microsoft MessageQueue is what I am refering to. I want to know how to monitor a MessageQueue using a windows service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible to create a multi-threaded windows service. Just spawn a new thread when you receive a message via your preferred way of handling things.

This is the manual way, you could also use a background worker:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => {  
   // Do some work  
});
```

There's nothing preventing a windows service from working like any other application - except for displaying user interfaces.